# How to set build options (-D) dynamically in XCode?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I'm porting a project to be built with MacOS. We compile the current source revision number into our code which is used to track version compatibility between files and libraries at a code level.

```
-DSRC_REVISION=12345
```

In our existing build system 12345 is output (as text) by a script called by make and turned into a build option each time make is run.

How might I do the same in XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use a `#define` in a .h file instead of doing a `-D` on the compile?

Change your script to write a "version.h" consisting of:

```
#define SRC_REVISION 12345
```

and then include that file in each of your source files (or set it up as a [prefix header](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/800-Reducing_Build_Times/bs_speed_up_build.html) so you don't have to explicitly include it in every file).

Comment: That would work except that its not automatic:  i) whoever is driving XCode needs to know there's a script to run, ii) they need to remember to run the script each time they update the source tree.

Comment: Resolved this by add "Add" > "New Build Phase" > "New Run Script Build Phase" to build version.h. Thanks.